# Fedora Package Changelogs

Tags: parsing, fedora, yum, rpm-spec, changelog

Does anyone know of a good place to find changelogs for Fedora packages? I'm looking to parse some data from these changelogs and have had difficulty finding anything reliable.

My current thinking is to parse the RPM spec files for the data I'm interested in (date, version #, etc.), but I have been unable to find any good pre-existing libraries to do this.

Additionally, fedora's website outlines standards for these changelogs:
* date developer_name  version_num
- entries

However, in my findings many spec files are inconsistent within this format and miss fields (typically the version number).

Anybody have any good ideas on this subject?

Answer (score 0):

If just looking for version, date, etc., you might try parsing `yum info <packagename>` or `rpm -qip <packagename>`.

If you specifically need something from the change log, then try `yum-changelog` plugin or `rpm -q --changelog <packagename>`. (Not sure, but when using `yum-changelog` it might add that info to the sqlite database used by yum. Then you could just query that info.)

I don't know of any kind of web service that you could gather this info from.

Comment: Right, so one specific thing I need from the changelog (can't find it anywhere else) is a direct association of CVE numbers and the version of a package they apply to. I've had trouble getting this information anywhere else online. My thought is to use the changelogs for this since its all in one place...any other thoughts? Thanks for the feedback.

Comment: Ah, ok. That's how [this site](http://www.cyberciti.biz/faq/linux-find-out-patch-can-cve-applied/) explains finding the CVEs. I also read somewhere that "RHN Satellite Server makes it much easier to get the CVEs and RHSA (Security Advisories) for all systems, in one, concise view."